# Cannot get types intellisense for vue, vuex in javascript

Tags: typescript-typings

I installed vue, vuex, because they provide their own type definitions, vscode don't give me any parameter info. how can I get type info in javascript

Comment: I can manually copy their types to %appdata%\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\node_modules\@types, is there any automatic solution

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Vetur - a VS Code extension for Vue.JS

You can install it through VS Codes extension library.

https://github.com/vuejs/Vetur